# 409 conflict error when deleting multiple attachments using PnP js or REST

Tags: rest, spfx, attachments, promises

I am trying to delete multiple attachments from list item as below

```
private _deleteOneByOneAttachment(ln: string, id: any, file: any):Promise<any>{
    let item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(ln).items.getById(id);
    return item.attachmentFiles.getByName(file).delete().then(v => {
        return v;
    }) as Promise<any>;
  }
```

I am calling above function in promise.all

```
    b.Files.forEach(k=>{
             delArray.push(this._deleteOneByOneAttachment(this.state.appsUsedByStateList,b.ID,k));
                    });
 Promise.all(delArray)
```

if there 4 attachments to delete then 2 are getting deleted and remaining it is giving conflict error, 409.

What is the right way to delete attachments from list item

Comment: how are you getting values in `b.Files` ??

Comment: b.Files contains file names to delete, b.Id contains item id

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deleteMultiple` method to delete multiple attachments of a list item.

It expects a string array containing names of the files.

You can use it as below:

```
let list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Custom List");

list.items.getById(2).attachmentFiles.deleteMultiple("1.txt","abc.png","test.docx").then(r => {
    console.log(r);
});
```

[PnPJS working with Attachments](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/attachments/)

Comment: I have tried with this code also earlier. But this is also giving same issue

Comment: can you try using `recycleMultiple` instead and check ?

Comment: Sorry, what is recycleMultiple? Is it a method name?

Comment: Yes, it sends attachments to recycle bin instead of permanently deleting the attachments

Comment: Can you give me reference for this method?

Comment: It's the same as deletemultiple with same parameters.

Comment: Check this, [Recycle Multiple Attachments](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/attachments/#recycle-multiple-attachments).